# How to get metadata from a picture?

Tags: android, bitmap, metadata

I am browsing the web but no way to find how to get metadata from a picture.

Does anyone has an idea ?

I can't see anything in the Bitmap/BitmapFactory/BitmapFactory.Options documentation that would give me a hint.

I would like to retrieve standard information such as :

- name
- date it was taken
- dimension
- size

and maybe more.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get at least the size of the image by setting BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds to true.

If the image is in the MediaStore, you might be able to get more information.

Answer (score 2):

According to this thread

http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-02/msg00821.html

you have to use ImageManager

Comment: The link shows a white page and has one line of text: `Error, Will Robinson!`. The thread seems gone.